# Respond with both body and status code in Nancy

Tags: nancy

I'm new to Nancy and I want to return both a custom HttpStatusCode and a body (content).  If I return an HttpStatusCode, it returns it with a blank body.  If I return a string then it returns that as the body but always with a 200 status code of OK.

```
public class SendSMS : NancyModule
{
    public SendSMS()
    {
        Post["/SendSMS"] = parameters =>
            {
                return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest; // this works, no body
                return "Missing \"to\" parameter"; // this works, 200 status code
                // want to return status code with message
            };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could always create an instance of the `Response` type and set the `Body` and `StatusCode` yourself. If you wanted to take a shortcut you could do something like

```
var r = (Response)"Some string that goes into the body";
r.StatusCode = 123;

return r;
```

Answer (score 17):

This should work.

```
public class SendSMS : NancyModule
{
   public SendSMS()
   {
       Post["/SendSMS"] = parameters =>
       {
           return Negotiate.WithModel("Missing \"to\" param")
                           .WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)           
       };
   }
}
```

For more information check the docs on [controlling content negotiation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Content-Negotiation#controlling-the-negotiation).

Comment: Only problem with this method was that it was escaping the string and adding quotes around it.

Comment: Which version of Nancy are you using Anthony?

Answer (score 8):

This is the simplest way I've found:

Return from your Module:

```
return new Response {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ReasonPhrase = "Resource not found"
            };
```

Comment: ReasonPhrase is additional text to code not a response body.

Answer (score 7):

If you have problems with encoding it's better to use

```
return new TextResponse(HttpStatusCode.STATUS, "Text Responsé")
```