# In NancyFx how can I change return status code and set the response text?

Tags: c#, nancy

Using Nancy I can return a response like this:

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => {
            return "Hello World";
        };
    }
}
```

And I can return a status 400 like this:

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => {
            return HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        };
    }
}
```

How do I return a specific http status code and set the response text too?

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099843/respond-with-both-body-and-status-code-in-nancy

Comment: I vote to close my own question as a duplicate. The question found by @csprabala is exactly the question I'm asking, and the answer there works.

Comment: This should be closed, the link above is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you should implement a `IStatusCodeHandler` interface.

According the [documentation](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Generating-a-custom-error-page), I found some articles on this:

- [Custom Error Pages in NancyFx](http://mike-ward.net/2013/04/11/custom-error-pages-in-nancyfx/)
- [Custom error pages in Nancyfx (C# Web Framework)](https://blog.tommyparnell.com/custom-error-pages-in-nancy/)
- [Nancy and custom error pages (VB.NET code)](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/WebDev/ServerProgramming/nancy-and-custom-error-pages/)

So your code should be like this:

```
public class StatusCodeHandler : IStatusCodeHandler  
{  
    private readonly IRootPathProvider _rootPathProvider;  

    public StatusCodeHandler(IRootPathProvider rootPathProvider)  
    {  
        _rootPathProvider = rootPathProvider;  
    }  

    public bool HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)  
    {  
        return statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound;  
    }  

    public void Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)  
    {  
        context.Response.Contents = stream =>  
        {  
            var filename = Path.Combine(_rootPathProvider.GetRootPath(), "content/PageNotFound.html");  
            using (var file = File.OpenRead(filename))  
            {  
                file.CopyTo(stream);  
            }  
        };  
    }  
}
```

So we can see here:

1. A constructor for your class with information about your current root
   `StatusCodeHandler(IRootPathProvider rootPathProvider)`
2. A methods which decides, are we need to handle current request with this class
   `HandlesStatusCode(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)`
3. Handle method which adds to the `Response` contents the custom error file contents from your root directory
   `Handle(HttpStatusCode statusCode, NancyContext context)`

If for some reason this isn't an option for you, simply create an HttpResponse which needed status and text, like this:

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = parameters => {
            return new Response {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ReasonPhrase = "Hello World"
            };
        };
    }
}
```